# How can I correctly initialize a struct member of type thrust::device_vector?

Tags: c++, cuda, clion, thrust

What's the correct usage of `thrust::device_vector` as class member?

I am trying to write a struct, which has `thrust::device_vector` as its member. I expect the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

struct ABC
{
    ABC() : wh(3,10)
    {};
    void clear()
    {
        wh.clear();
    }
    thrust::device_vector<int> wh;
};


int main()
{
    ABC abc;
    std::cout << abc.wh.size() << std::endl;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < abc.wh.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << abc.wh[i] << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

to produce

```
3
10 10 10
```

but instead I'm getting

```
3
0 0 0
```

CLion also marks initialization of `wh` vector with an error of

```
ambiguous partial specializations of 'pointer_element<thrust::pointer<void, thrust::cuda_cub::tag, thrust::tagged_reference<void, thrust::cuda_cub::tag>>>'
```

but the code compiles without errors.

What's the nature of these errors which I'm getting from the IDE, and why the code compiles in the end?

Comment: I don't have any trouble with the code either on a machine with CUDA 12.0.  I'm not using Clion.  In the past I would have said to copy the element to the host first, before attempting to use it with `std::cout`, but thrust seems to have fixed that.  Might be dependent on your thrust version.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it works perfectly on Compiler Explorer. That's really odd. I've just tried to compile the code directly with NVCC (CUDA 12.0) from the terminal, and got the same result, so CLion is not the problem here. Could be that my device, which is an old GTX 750 TI (computing capability of 5.0 according to NVIDIA's website) somehow doesn't support such features? I wonder if that's the case, considering `thrust::device_vector` is a basic feature of Thrust.

Comment: When you compile for a cc5.0 device on cuda 12.0, you need to specify `-arch=sm_50` or similar.  CUDA 11 and 12 compile for a cc5.2 device by default, and that wouldn't work correctly on your GTX 750 Ti.  If this is the issue, I would have thought thrust would throw an error, however.

Comment: @RobertCrovella That's exactly what fixed the issue! Thank you, that really helped. I wonder why it compiles at all - no warning, no error, no issue whatsoever.